How to debug a specific method in VS Code (not main) using python
I have a method cli in mymodule which is the entrypoint for my programm. cli takes several keyword arguments. The module mymodule does not contain something like
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli(...)

How do i specify a run-configuration for this?
I tried
{
        "name": "myentrypoint",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "mymodule.cli",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "--arg1", "value1",
            "--arg2", "value2"
            ],
        "justMyCode": true
}

(as suggested in How to make VScode launch.json for a Python module)
This gives me
/home/xxxxxx/projects/myproject/.venv/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'mymodule.cli' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'mymodule' while trying to find 'mymodule.cli')

Normally I use this entrypoint using poetry like
[tool.poetry.scripts]
myentrypoint= 'mymodule:cli'

And then from the terminal
poetry run myentrypoint --arg1 "value1" --arg2 "value2
But now I need to debug the program

why would vscode support some custom capability like that?  if you don't want to add the main support into your module, then create a main.py and use that as your entrypoint.

@toppk because poetry supports it?

You could try to set cli in args. It looks like:
{
        "name": "myentrypoint",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "mymodule",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "cli",
            "--arg1", "value1",
            "--arg2", "value2"
            ],
        "justMyCode": true
}


this is not working

Are there any error messages or logs when you try to run or debug your Python CLI method in VS Code?

It's doing the imports in the file (initialization code), but the method "cli" is not entered... die program just ends without doing anything

I suggest you create main.py as entrypoint which include `from mymodule import cli
if name == "main":
   import sys
   cli(*sys.argv[1:])`
